# How do I add hyperlink to text in a form using zend forms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hii...

I would like to have the text hyper linked in between the content description using zend form, please suggest how I can do that ?? thanx in advance. Here is the code what I am trying to get the text hyper linked and it did not work, instead displaying the content as it is.

```
$selectTemplate = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('report_template');
$selectTemplate->setLabel('Select Template:')
            ->setDescription('No message templates have been added, add a message template <a href="admin-report-addreporttemplate">here</a>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the escape option of the Description decorator to false:

```
$selectTemplate->getDecorator('description')->setOption('escape', false);
```